# How do I add 1 hour to datetime SQL column data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, getdate, hour

I used this part of a query to create a table column for the date and time a row is added:

`order_date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()`

and whenever a new row is created, the data for `order_date` is set to something like this:

`Apr 8 2014 9:52AM`

For some reason, when a row is created and the `order_date` column data is set, the hour is set 1 hour back. For example, the above column data for `Apr 8 2014 9:52AM` was set at 10:52AM.

Is there a way to set it 1 hour ahead so that it is correct with my current time?

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the system time on your SQL Server.  Fix that, not the symptom.

Comment: The server's timezone may be off.

Comment: I can't, because it is not my server, therefore I cannot change the timezone.

Comment: @MatBailie got this one.  Check your system time.  The insert works off of that and if your timezone is off, it'll set it to the wrong timezone.

Comment: @Kelsey - And if they fix the time after you put in place your fix?

Comment: If you are working in an environment like that you may want to consider `getutcdate()` instead since everything will be off and you will need to adjust everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider using [DATETIMEOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) as your daatype instead of DATETIME.

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of a day that has time
>   zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock.

You can use it with [SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx)).

```
Returns a datetimeoffset(7) value that contains the date and time of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running. The time zone offset is included.
```

Example:

```
 CREATE TABLE DateTest (id INT, order_date DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
 INSERT INTO DateTest (id) VALUES (1)
 SELECT * FROM DateTest
```

Comment: I am using `date_default_timezone_set('America/Edmonton');` on my PHP page so I hope it will set the date/time to that. How would I go about creating a query to create a table column for this type of data?

Comment: SQL Server DATETIME doesn't have Time Zone info in it so PHP cannot do anything with it without more info. I'll might not have to time to add the query, but it's basically the same just using the different type and different function.

Comment: Very good answer, here is an up vote. I would appreciate an up vote on my question, if possible.

Answer (score 38):

Use DATEADD()

```
DATEADD(hh, 1, order_date)
```

EDIT:

If the time is being set an hour back, you may have a wrong system time. So, it would be better if you just ask server admin to correct it.

Comment: How would I use this in a query? (DATEADD(hh, 1, order_date))

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (DATEADD(hh, 1, order_date)). You supply the rest of the columns.

Comment: This is what I am using right now and it doesn't seem to be inserting any new rows: `$sql5="INSERT INTO tracking_orders (account_id, order_date) VALUES ('".$acc_id."',' DATEADD(hh, 1, order_date)')"`

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQL SERVER?

Comment: Yes, I am using `MSSQL`.

Comment: But, I am running the query on my PHP page.

Comment: You can't use that method in PHP. What you can do is create a Stored Procedure in MSSQL, put the DATEADD() method there and then call the SP in PHP.

Comment: I don't have access to the CPanel, so I have to do everything through PHP, unfortunately.

Comment: You can use something like:
update Test set YourDate = DATEADD(hh, 1, order_date) where IdTest = 1